# Is there any solution to find element by isOffScreen property from inspect.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, automation, winappdriver

[inspect.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdOvE.png)

Hi guys, may I know any way to access this "isOffscreen" element from inspect.exe.
Because I only found the driver support accessibilityId or others elements but without isOffscreen.

Because now my UI have two similar button automation id, so it unable to detect the button that I want to access, so i want to make a condition which the isOffscreen = false then only detect the clickable point.

Any way to help this out? Thanks :)

```
var temp = _xilnexSession.FindElementsByAccessibilityId("btnNext");
var temp2 = _xilnexSession.FindElement("isOffScreen", "false");        
int ii = 0;
        foreach(WindowsElement e in temp)
        {
            
            if (ii == 1 && isOffscreen)
            {
                e.Click();
                break;
            }
            ii++;
        }
```

Comment: Is `isOffscreen` really a `element` you can find?

Comment: I noticed that findelement not a good solution to access the value of isOffScreen.

Comment: use GetAttribute("isOffscreen") then only get the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (WindowsElement e in temp)
{
     string obejct = e.GetAttribute("IsOffscreen");
     if (e.GetAttribute("IsOffscreen") == "False")
     {
          e.Click();
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Short explanation what your code does would be good.